# open wpf window in Revit as add ins

Tags: wpf, add-in, revit

I made a project using WPF and I want to open its window in Revit I trying windows form it worked but wpf not opened !!

I use this

```
public virtual Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        IDesign.MainWindow testsd = new IDesign.MainWindow();
        testsd.InitializeComponent();
        //MessageBox.Show("notworking");
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
```

But it didn't work any solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public virtual Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        IDesign.MainWindow testsd = new IDesign.MainWindow();
        //testsd.InitializeComponent();
        //MessageBox.Show("notworking");
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }

 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a WPF User Control and assign it as the Content of a WPF window in a Revit External Command, something like:

```
UserControl1 userControl = new UserControl1();
Window win = new Window();
win.Content = userControl;
win.Show();
```